# Birchas Ilanos on Fig Trees

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits, agriculture, trees

Can one say *Birchas Ilanos* on a [fig tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_fig#Pollination.2C_fruit.2C_and_propagation)?

Answer (score 1):

Modern-day botanical classifications should not have an impact on the application of this berachah. From a halachic standpoint, the fig is certainly considered a "fruit," and its emergence is presumably equivalent to לבלוב, hence the berachah could be said on it. (Intersting question, though!)

Comment: Sources please?

Comment: I own a fig tree and can tell you that one does not see the blossoms budding. The blossoms are shielded by syconia.

Comment: I was thinking of the image on that wiki page (http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Ficus_bud.JPG/220px-Ficus_bud.JPG), which did look like a kind of blossoming. But I hear what you're saying.